# ExtJS Grid Paging Row Selection

Tags: javascript, extjs, selection

Is there anyway in the ExtJS Grid to select a row that is located in another page, when the PagingToolbar is used.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say select, do you mean actually highlight...or retrieve?

If the record is on another page, you cant 'highlight' it because its not visible- in that case, what you may want to do is highlight it on the page change event:

```
nameofpagingtoolbar.on('change', function(nameofdatagrid.getView().focusRow(X));});
```

Where X is the index (integer) of the row you wish to select.

If you wish to retrieve information in a record, again, using X as the index you can use:

```
nameofdatagrid.getStore().getAt(X).data.nameoffield;
```

Note however that you cant access records on another page if the paging type is set to remote...